# Saving an argument given by user in a register in xv6

Tags: operating-system, xv6

We are supposed to add a system call to the xv6 OS which counts the digits of a given number.
For doing so we should save the number in a register and then make a function that reads that argument from the register and passes it to the function handling the logic of the system call.
My question is: how should we save the argument given by the user in a register?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean that the number should be received as an argument to the system call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a value into system call XV6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870509/how-to-pass-a-value-into-system-call-xv6)

Answer (score 1):

there are general registers in xv6 that you can use for reading and writing in user programs. there is no function in c for writing an int value into a register but you can use inline assembly c for doing so.
for example if your variable is a and you want to save it in eax register you can use this code:

```
asm ("movl %0, %%eax;" 
     :       /* no output */
     :"r"(a) /* input is variable a */
     :"%eax" /* clobbered register */      
     );
```

for more information about how to write in registers with inline c assembly you can read this site: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s5

Answer (score 0):

When the user want to use a system call, he use it like a function, for instance : `kill(int)`:

In usys.S, `kill` is defined:

```
SYSCALL(kill)
```

Which is translated to

```
  .globl kill; 
  kill: 
    movl $SYS_ ## open, %eax; 
    int $T_SYSCALL; 
    ret
```

So when `kill` is called by user, the interrupt handler launch `sys_kill`:

```
int
sys_kill(void)
{
  int pid;

  if(argint(0, &pid) < 0)
    return -1;
  return kill(pid);
}
```

And as you can see, the line `if(argint(0, &pid) < 0)` is responsible to read the **first** (0) argument given to the function invoqued by the user.
And with this, the kernel function `kill` is called, but it's not the same that the user called.

---

So to answer you simply:

- declare your syscall in defs.h with the correct number of parameters, like `count_digit(int)`
- make your syscall handler:

  ```
  sys_count_digit(void)
  {
      int digit;
      if (argint(0, &digit) < 0)
        return -1;
      return count_digit(digit);   
  }
  ```
- implement the kernel code for `count_digit`